# Web Game Resolution

Tags: resolution, web

I'm starting on a new game that I intend to release via the web (HTML + Javascript). I would like to be able to make a reasonable decision about what screen resolution sizes to support, and what percentage of players can comfortably play my game at increasing resolutions.

Any answer is temporal, so I'm looking for a solution that's up-to-date. For example, I looked at the Steam hardware/software survey -- which is what I want, but data is skewed heavily towards desktop gamers (eg. some of the most common resolutions look like they span two screens).

Where can I find constantly updated data about screen resolutions for my in-browser game?

Comment: Can I assume you only need landscape? With this, I mean that smartphones will be forced to rotate screen.

Comment: @HatoruHansou yes, that's a pretty safe assumption. If I ever make a portrait-orientation game (which I have done on occasion), I can just flip the width/height dimensions.

Comment: Are you sure you looked at the right line? [Here](http://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey), take a look at _Primary Display Resolution_.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I'm pretty sure I looked at the right line. I can't access the Steam website right now, but from memory, it was `3840 x <something>`, which I interpreted (perhaps wrongly) as two 1080p monitors. Regardless, I still think Steam's survey is heavily biased towards PC gaming.

Comment: You're right, it is biased toward PC gaming. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkej4.png) is a screenshot for your convenience.

Comment: Close-voters, can you please clarify why you think this question is off-topic?

Comment: The close votes I see call it "primarily opinion-based" - I think by that they mean that it's difficult to identify an objective standard here. It will depend heavily on what audience each game chooses to target - eg. to what extent do your players use high-end PCs, netbooks, tablets, phones - which phones? How old is the min-spec hardware you plan to support? Etc. On desktop, do your players maximize their browser or keep it half-size while they chat in the other half of the screen? We could offer conservative numbers, but my conservative number may be different from another person's.

Comment: @DMGregory I thought that's the point of the question entirely: point me to some data where I can make those decisions meaningfully, with data, instead of guessing.

Comment: I haven't voted to close this question, so I can only speculate - debating with me won't undo those votes. ;) I imagine these users may consider "find the data I want for me" to be a question for a search engine - any answer we give will tend to age poorly as hardware & use habits change and links rot. Plus, as you note, Steam data skews to hardcore PC players, and other sources have similar biases. So even "which data sets should I consult" could be argued to be a matter of opinion. Narrowing the question to avoid these interpretations could help address these concerns.

Comment: @DMGregory I'm not sure I understand (and I'm not debating, I'm trying to understand your view). I tried editing my question; is it better, or worse?

Comment: If you use server-side programming language, try [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/), it's sounds like what you want. But I recommend you try to make your game responsive by CSS/JS since you're on the web, making it responsive is relatively easy

Answer (score 1):

With the web you really can't assume anything about the user's resolution.

People browse the web with all kinds of devices. PCs, tablets, smartphones, even smart TVs. Even if you decide to only target PCs, you can not assume that the user maximized their browser window. So it might have any size whatsoever.

To deal with this problem, try to design your game in a way that it can zoom smoothly and its UI so that it adapts well to different resolutions. If you simply can't manage with a variable aspect ratio, your last resort is letterboxing/pillarboxing (keep the game in the aspect ratio, make it as large as possible and add black bars on the side or on top).

Comment: I've actually never played a web game that zoomed (and I've accumulated a number of badges on Kongregate). Just to be clear, are you suggesting zooming in-game, or telling users to use their browser zoom?